# Dynamically change hibernate mapping when database columns are changed

Tags: c#, sql, xml, service, hibernate-mapping

I have a database with next tables (simplified):

TPersons:
FId - primary key, int - Id of person
FName - nvarchar(100) - name of person

TOtherFields:
FId - primary key, int - Id of additional field
FName - nvarchar(100) - field name in the database

TOtherValues:
FPersonId - foreign key, int - Id of person
FField1, FField2,... - set of fields that are defined in TOtherFields.

For example, we have 2 records in TOtherFields ({1, "FField1"} and {2, "FField2"}, then we have columns "FField1" and "FField2" in the table TOtherValues.

I have 2 applications.
The first app can change database, add new additional fields and fill data of persons and their additional fields.
The second app is a service on C#, that uses hibernate mapping to work with this database.

For this example it has next mapping files:

Person.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  assembly="MyApp.Common.Model"
  namespace="MyApp.Common.Model">
  <class name="Person" entity-name="Person" table="TPersons" polymorphism="explicit">
    <id name="Id" column="FId">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SEQ_TPERSONS</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <one-to-one name="AddFields" entity-name="AddFields" fetch="join" cascade="all"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

AdditionalFields.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  assembly="MyApp.Common.Model"
  namespace="MyApp.Common.Model">
  <class name="AddFields" entity-name="AddFields" table="TOtherValues" polymorphism="explicit">
    <id name="Id" column="FPersonId">
    </id>
    <property name="FField1" not-null="false" access="MyApp.Common.Model.AddFieldsAccessor, MyApp.Common.Model"/>
    <property name="FField2" not-null="false" access="MyApp.Common.Model.AddFieldsAccessor, MyApp.Common.Model"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It works fine while I don't change fields with 1st app.

result of GET request:

```
{
    "AdvancedFields": {
        "Fields": {
            "FOTHER1": "text1",
            "FOTHER2": "02.02.2020"
        },
        "Id": 1,
        "TypeId": "AddFields"
    },
    "Id": 1,
    "TypeId": "Person"
}
```

I should make this service works when I change fields with 1st application. For example, I added "FField3" to the database - new record to TOtherFields table and new column to TOtherValues.
My service should find it out some way and show this new field in his Get request. Maybe this AddFields.hbm.xml should be changed and reloaded by service, maybe I should add "FField3" with some key "skip-if-not-exists" before it, maybe some other way. But I can't restart the service, and it should return Persons with all additional fields that there are in database.

Comment: Does it work after you reboot the machine?

Comment: if I change AddFields.hbm.xml, it works when I restart service or machine. It loads xml configuration on service start and don't change configuration after it. So I need to change it while service is working.

Comment: I do not know if that is possible.  When I add columns to a database using SQL Server Management Studio I usually have to close SSMS before my c# recognizes the changes when the c# has already access the database.  c# maintains a connection list and never tried disposing list.

Comment: Maybe I can fill list of fields and mark them "skip if not exists" so it will return valid information for persons with all existed fields. Or maybe I can setup a kind of "dinamic list of fields" that will read columns of table and fill a schema.

Comment: As I said, I do not know if it is possible.